# Slide a div using animate(), hide it

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide

I am trying to animate a div so it slides up, using animate(). This is easy enough, the catch is that I want it to tuck up under the toggle button above it (with higher z-index) and **disappear**. In other words, I don't want to see the div come up above the button. This would be easy if the button (or something) above it stretched to the edge of the screen, but it doesn't.

I tried using height, but this shortens the div from the bottom up, not the other way around. My code is on Code Pen: http://codepen.io/solona/pen/NqPmpp

```
<div class='column'>
    <button class='toggle'>Hide Text</button>
    <div class='drawer'>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.column {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: lightgrey;
    padding: 1em;
}

.toggle {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
}

.drawer {
  padding: 1em;
  background: pink;
  position: relative;
}
```

```js
$(".toggle").click(function() {
    if ($(".drawer").hasClass('open')) {
        $(".drawer").animate({
            'bottom': $(".drawer").height()
        }, 400);
        $(this).html("Show Text");
        $(".drawer").removeClass('open');
    } else if (!$(".drawer").hasClass('open')) {
        $(".drawer").animate({
            'bottom': '0px'
        }, 400);
        $(this).html("Hide Text");
        $(".drawer").addClass('open');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Put a wrapper around `.drawer` that has overflow set to hidden:

```
.bureau {overflow: hidden;}
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqPdGM)**

You'll need to tweak padding, etc., to remove the remaining space.

Comment: Ah! I tried overflow:hidden, but in the wrong place. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Playing with your code on Codepen .. what about this as an option ...

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  if ($(".drawer").hasClass('open')) {
    $(".drawer").animate({
      'bottom': $(".drawer").height()
    }, 400).animate({
      opacity: 0
    });
    $(this).html("Show Text");
    $(".drawer").removeClass('open');
  } else if (!$(".drawer").hasClass('open')) {
    $(".drawer").animate({
      opacity: 100
    }).animate({
      'bottom': '0px'
    }, 400);
    $(this).html("Hide Text");
    $(".drawer").addClass('open');
  }
});
```